# Use Lucene Similarity's Coord value as hit score

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Is there a way to return only a Similarity's Coord value as a hit's score? I've overridden every combination of methods I could think of to get this result with no luck. Actually, the score doesn't have to be the exact Coord value, but all hits should be relative to each other based on that value and nothing else.

For example, if I search "Test Search String" and hit on two words, I want that score to be 66% of the score of a hit on all three words.

This is in Lucene.net 2.9.4, but I can translate any Java implementations as needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried it so I don't know if it would work, but you could  probably create your own implementation of [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) and use it by calling the `Searcher.SetSimilarity()` method.

Have every methods but `Coord()` of your `Similarity` return 1. The `Coord()` method could simply read:

```
return overlap / (float) maxOverlap;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had the setup you mentioned, but I had my casting wrong (`return (float)(overlap / maxOverlap)`), which always returned 0.